# How can I light a large area and prevent spawns?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a large box that I'm building in, about 100x100x20. I have placed Glowstone all around the perimeter, lines of Glowstone every 10 blocks for the length and width of the floor, as well as Glowstone on the walls at 10x intervals at the 7 and 17 mark up the 20x wall.

Suffice to say I would think this is a lit space, however I still get spawns:

[image: Inside of box with lines of glowstone and spawned spiders]

If I am across the room, up high and looking down, the ground is in shadows. Not dark, just darker that I would expect. If I move over to the location it typically takes a couple of seconds for the 'light' to pop and brighten up the area.

I don't have a slow computer but is this just lag or something else? Its pretty consistent if I am some place in the room the lights dim in the farthest location away.

---

- I am playing Minecraft v1.2.5
- This building is built in Flat/Creative mode, so I am probably 5-6 levels above Bedrock.
- Originally I had a lot LESS blocks in place, that was when I noticed the issue originally and then I went overkill on the lighting, and it didn't change anything.
- I don't know if it factors into things but the building splits 3 biomes: desert, grass and snow. Actually there is a diagonal swatch of snow that cuts thru the building from corner to corner. I can have desert , snow storms and then grass and rain all within a couple of steps.

Comment: I've seen this happen often with the new lighting engine. Usually it'll update the light if you temporarily change the light on that block. For example, remove a few glowstone blocks then replace them. Unusual amount of unlit blocks, however, so this may be nothing more than conjecture.

Comment: A glowstone set into the floor loses 1 unit of light to travel up.  So there's 14 points in the air cube above it.  This is the same as putting a torch on the floor.

Answer (score 5):

You can press F3 to bring up the debug information, there is information regarding the light level of the block your head is in. So you need to keep it above 8 (so the floor is above 7).

[image: Debug screen]
The number you need to pay attention to is rl (real light) as long as this is high enough mobs cannot spawn.

Comment: very useful, didn't know that.  Still, what does it have to do with a large shadowy section in an area almost filled with light sources?

Comment: @SomeMiscGuy I'll help you find the areas that are spawning the mobs...

Comment: OK, so stupid question of the moment, since the pattern of light is diamond shaped do glowstones with only their tops showing just not give off enough light?

Answer (score 5):

If preventing spawns is your main objective, and you don't mind it looking a bit dark, you can lay a floor of half-slabs. This will prevent mobs from spawning at all, regardless of light level.

Answer (score 1):

the best thing is to do floating torches,rather a block
 with a 5x5x5 radius so its in the middle of a 5x5x5 cube and put torches everywhere but the bottom with a 5x5x5 cube around it and the half slabs thing is true

Answer (score 0):

If preventing monsters spawning is your main objective and you don’t mind it being too dark, I would recommend putting command blocks set to

`repeat` and `always active` under the floor and setting them to use the command:

`/kill @e[type=<replace this with entity you want to kill> r=<range in which you want them to be killed>]`. That way the entities won’t spawn.

I hope this helped you.